# Best way to display hundreds of thumbnails on page

Tags: php, image, page-load-time

The web page has a requirement to display a large number of thumbnails on a page, in rows that fit the viewport. Images are set to a height of 160px. The image filenames come from a database, so a loop is used to create the `<img>` tag.

The images are displayed in a randomized order, handled by the query. There are currently about 2100 images, with more added each day.

The issue is how to optimize the loading of the images most efficiently. I realize it will take a while to load all of the images in the viewport, not to mention outside the viewport ('below the fold').

Assume that the thumbnail images are optimized as for filesize. Also, the number of images per row needs to adjust to the viewport width.

What is the best method to display such a large number of images on a page? And to 'prepare' for the images that will appear if the visitor scrolls the page?

**Additional assumptions/requirements (added)**

The requirement is that the number of items to display in a viewport depends on how many will 'fit'. So how to determine how many items (each say 150p x 300p width by height) will fit in the current viewport - to make the display of the items in the viewport area more 'efficient'.

That would require some computing by some JS on the client side. So some client-side code would have to change the img tag for the images in the viewport to make them visible, while using a lazy-load (?) to load/defer loading the images outside the viewport?

** Added **

The images are about 25-30K in side, all are jpg. The img tag specifies a height of 150px; the images are 100-150px height.

The code that displays the images loops through the list of available images, putting them all in one div, so they are displayed left-right/top-bottom. Images do not always load in that sequence, sometimes a few images in a 'row' will not load right after the one next to it.

So, I am looking for an efficient way to display the images in the viewport (first) and then display the rest as the viewport is scrolled. And the display and technique needs to be responsive for different size viewports.

Comment: Additional info, and a more specific question, added.

Answer (score 2):

You should use lazy loading for your images. And reduce file-size of your images.

You might want to lazy load all images below the fold, when your images will appear inside the viewport lazy load them.

For image-size reduction there are several techniques, a few simple ones are:

- Use jpg instead of png or gif
- Make sure your images are static, and not preparsed through php or someting like that
- Reduce image quality to 20% or 30%, but increasing the image to 200%. Which means that if your images are 160px in height, save your original images to 320px in height, but reduce the quality of the jpg file to around 20%. This will reduce your file size a lot! The original image of 320px in height is not nice to see, but when you add it to a 160px height container it's a better image.

Something like this:

```
<img src="my-320px-20pquality-image.jpg" style="height:160px" />
```

*Advanced*:

- If you control the webserver which serves images (like a private CDN) remove cookie parsing. This will reduce server load time.
- Use a CDN to serve your static files

Comment: A CDN is not an option for the images (non-profit). No cookies are used (other than a GDPR cookie set for a first-time visitor).

Comment: I ment cookies on the image url. If your images are served from an apache server on mydomain.com/images/ then you can disable cookies with a .htaccess for that subfolder. If you use nginx, you should edit the conf files. This way the server will not parse cookies on that path, and will be a few ms quicker per image, but if you serve a few hundred, then it's much quicker!

Answer (score 1):

You definitly should add some pagination or load images by some ajax requests to optimize page load.

An example of how you do is Firstly show 20 of them by limiting the query to 20. whenever the user clicks "Load More" it loads 20 more thumbnails an so on until end. If you load that much amount of images at once the page may take some time to load.

Edit: You can even bind an event to the scroll and whenever the user comes to end of thumbnails you request 20 more.